# Sequel Table updates Slow: Wrong use of Sequel object abstraction? Network parameters?

Tags: ruby, database, sequel

I am updating an existing table with something like this:

```
 def upload_airports_mariadb(city,...)
     airport=Airport.find_or_create(City: city)
     airport.AirportID=airportid
     airport.TimeZone=timezone
     airport.save
   end
```

While airport is a simple model:

```
require 'sequel'
class Airport < Sequel::Model
  set_primary_key [:City]

  # Allow to set primary key using mass assignment.
  unrestrict_primary_key

end
```

Used in a webui for a single access per click this is fine but when using same code for a huge number of updates for the table in a loop this is terrible slow.
Is this the price for not reading the whole table, adjusting it ans writing it back in a single blop? 
To be honest I enjoy the object-like feeling and would not really like to deal with tables.

The observation that makes me feel hopeful is that the speed is depending on my network connection type.

Is there a way to tell sequel to keep the connection open? Updating 7k values takes up to 40 minutes.. this is horrible slow

currently I just call

```
@db = Sequel.connect("mysql2://path)
```

Why is it so slow?

Comment: `upload_airports_mariadb` will use 3 queries for a city that is not in table: first it will 'SELECT' to find there is no record, then it will create it with 'INSERT' and finally it will overwrite it again with `UPDATE` during `airport.save` call. You can spare on insert by using `airport = Airport[city] || Airport.new(City: city)`.

Sequel has logging, make sure to turn it on and check how long it takes for your query. Perhaps it is not Sequel or database, but the code that invokes the `update_airport` method.

Comment: You might want to wrap your loop in a transaction ://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/transactions.rdoc
That's an easy first improvement that prevents you from dealing with sql.

Comment: I tried already to surround the calling block with db.transaction do..end. The pity is that the log shows still a lot of queries eac close to my ping times but far too many.